# ASP.NET - Hide and Show Griview Column Conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a gridview that should hide certain column/s when one condition in searching options is chosen. Otherwise, that column should be viewed.

I already did hiding a column using this code:

```
grdMarketingReport1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
```

But when i search another condition that should show that column, it is no longer showing. take note that gridview property Autogeneratecolumn is set to false

**updated**

**on BUTTON CLICK EVENT**

```
  if ((txtHiddenLoc.Text == "ALL") && (txtHiddenBus.Text == "ALL"))
                        {
                            executeQuery();
                            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[2].Visible = true;
                        }


else if (((txtHiddenLoc.Text == "ALL") && (txtHiddenBus.Text != "ALL")) 

                        {
                            executeQuery();
                            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[2].Visible = false;

                        }
```

..

```
public void executeQuery()
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spMarketingReport1", con);
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RP", txtHiddenRP.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", txtHiddenLoc.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom1", txtdatefrom1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo1", txtdateto1.Text);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        grdMarketingReport1.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
        grdMarketingReport1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        grdMarketingReport1.DataBind();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
```

it hides the column correctly , but when another condition applies where it is to VIEW back the column, the data / values on the column is emptied.

Comment: Where are you setting this? Button click? Page load? Have you reset the visibility for the positive condition?

Comment: this is on button click

Comment: Is `executeQuery()` called in page load at all? If so is it called in `if (!Page.isPostBack)`? Also what about when `txtHiddenLoc.Text != "ALL"`

Comment: no they are not in page load. Ive decided not to put the whole codes as it may be irrelevant and just make the question longer. txthiddenLoc is a actually a hiddenfield, whenever the user chooses ALL option in a modalpopup, the system will put a value ALL in the txthiddenloc as well as in the txtHiddenBus

Answer (score 0):

I'd set the visibility of you column using your search condition. Also try re-sequencing the order.

```
bool displayCol = ((txtHiddenLoc.Text == "ALL") && (txtHiddenBus.Text == "ALL"));
executeQuery();
grdMarketingReport1.Columns[2].Visible = dispalyCol;
```

If this doesn't work, try hiding and displaying the column in the [DataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Pre-Render](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.prerender%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of the grid view.

Comment: This does hide and show the column, BUT after viewing the column again,   the values on that column became empty

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on RowDataBound event of Grid

```
Protected Sub grdMarketingReport1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdMarketingReport1.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
        If Checkbox.Checked = True Then
            e.Row.Cells(2).Style("display") = "none"
        End IF
    End IF

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If Checkbox.Checked = True Then
            e.Row.Cells(2).Style("display") = "none"
        End IF
    End IF

End Sub
```

Comment: I've done this actually but it hides the column regardless of my condition

Comment: You can put condition also on Gridview HeaderRow as well as DataRow.
Check code. May it can help you.

Comment: Yes this should help. Or use inline condition using Eval and Binder.Expression

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the simplest answer, just put this showing and hiding code BEFORE the databinding of gridview,. Just like this:

```
**grdMarketingReport1.Columns[2].Visible = true;
  grdMarketingReport1.DataBind();**
```

AND PUT THE CONDITION INSIDE THE TRY CLAUSE inside the executeQuery()

```
    try
    {
        con.Open();

        if ((txtHiddenBus.Text == "NONE") && (txtHiddenRP.Text == "NONE"))
        {
            grdMarketingReport1.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
            grdMarketingReport1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[3].Visible = false;
            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[4].Visible = false;
            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[5].Visible = false;
            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[6].Visible = false;
            grdMarketingReport1.DataBind();
        }

        else if ((txtHiddenBus.Text != "NONE") && (txtHiddenRP.Text == "NONE"))
        {
            grdMarketingReport1.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
            grdMarketingReport1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[2].Visible = false;

            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[4].Visible = false;
            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[5].Visible = false;
            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[6].Visible = false;
            grdMarketingReport1.DataBind();
        }

        else
        {
            grdMarketingReport1.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
            grdMarketingReport1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[1].Visible = true;
            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[2].Visible = true;
            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[3].Visible = true;
            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[4].Visible = true;
            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[5].Visible = true;
            grdMarketingReport1.Columns[6].Visible = true;
            grdMarketingReport1.DataBind();
        }



    }
```